# Get indexes of array as number, in a for...in loop (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript1.7, typescript1.8

A `for..in` loop in JavaScript, iterates over the keys of the object passed in, and in case of an array iterates over the indexes of the array. Until Typescript 1.7 the index's type was a **number** but as from Typescript 1.8, index is a **string**! So I have a function that takes the index as a number and now I need to parse the index to a number like this `+index`.

Is this the recommended way or there is another way (in Typescript 1.8) to iterate over indexes of the array as numbers instead of strings?

Comment: Use `.forEach()` or a plain `for` loop with a numeric index that you increment yourself. It's generally considered bad practice to iterate over arrays with a `for ... in` loop. Object property names, including array indexes, are *always* strings (well, unless they're Symbols I guess, once that becomes more generally available).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, I guess I will prefer a plain for loop whenever I need a numeric index.